# Capture Video using ffmpeg / mobile-ffmpeg

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg

I have to use the **FFmpeg** in my project. I have integrated `mobile-ffmpeg`
according to instruction given. 
[github/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg)

I have used the pod which is as following.

```
pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-full'
```

I have to open the camera and I have executed the command as following.

```
[MobileFFmpeg execute: @"-f avfoundation -r 30 -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format bgr0 -i 0:0 -vcodec h264_videotoolbox -vsync 2 -f h264 -t 00:00:05 %@", recordFilePath];
```

It also asked the permission for camera, also for microphone then log starts appearing that camera is capturing the video, but there is no camera preview. After saving the video I found the link in the documents directory, but those links do not get played.

I also executed the commands given by the library for video information and other but they always went in the failure case.

Any help, sample project, wrapper(`Objecitve-C` or `Swift`), instruction please.

Comment: Can you use default UIImagePickerController and then use ffmpeg for any conversion....! May I know why you are using ffmpeg in your app?

Comment: Video Filters on live previews.

Comment: I don't believe `-vcodec h264_videotoolbox` is available on iOS. Can you verify once please.

Comment: Looks like there is no wrapper available for iOS for FFMpeg.

Comment: I faced up with the same issue. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @igdev I have to use native solution. No FFmpeg solution.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time to figure out what I do wrong. And finally, I figure out how to record video using ffmpeg-mobile.
My code looks like:

```
let temp = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
let outputFilePath = temp.absoluteString + UUID().uuidString + ".mp4"
MobileFFmpeg.execute("-f avfoundation -r 60 -video_size 1280x720 -i 0:0 -vcodec h264_videotoolbox -vsync 2 -f mp4 -t 00:00:05 " + outputFilePath)
```

For some reason which I don't know, `AVPlayer` cannot play `h264` videos. And it's why you will see infinity loading when you try to execute code from ffmpeg-mobile documentation